# Context Menu Binding in C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, contextmenu

When you set an observable collection as the item source of a context menu it lists the type of the each item...i would like to bind the name field of those items in the collection to the  header...I cant seem to figure out how to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [DisplayMemberPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.displaymemberpath.aspx) and put the name of the property on your item.  Or you could use the [ItemTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplate.aspx) property.

Example:

```
<ContextMenu ItemsSource="{Binding YourCollection}"
             DisplayMemberPath="Name" />
```

Comment: Thank you...I used the DisplayMemeberPath and it worked fine.